# How to Investigate the Usage of a TCP Port on Mac

Tags: terminal, network

I am getting an error that a port I am try to link in a `docker-compose` is being used by something else.

I can see my ports that are listening using suggested commands from here: [How can I list my open network ports with netstat?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117644/how-can-i-list-my-open-network-ports-with-netstat)

In my terminal I'm getting something looks approximately like the below:

```
Command   Pid         User     Fd    Type Device             Size/Off  Node    Name
java      343        _hivesvc  179u  IPv6 0x31e0f5f4193134b3      0t0  TCP     localhost:8999 (LISTEN)
```

How can I further investigate what is utilizing this port? I assume the Device is the detail I'm looking for? But the hexadecimal hash doesn't tell me anything I can interpret.

Comment: there seems to be a java process with PID 343 using that port

Comment: Is there a way I can take the PID and get the actual application name or directory that's running there?

Comment: Try ps -xEf -p PID

Comment: That worked, thank you. Happy to select your mark your answer as the solution if you want to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `ps -xEf -p PID` to see details about the process.